# Page Url by page type

Tags: asp.net, webformsmvp

Is there any way to get the Page Url by its page type ?

I'm trying to create an extension method that allows to redirect to pages using the page type instead of the URL

For a page called Index.asxp

I need to get "Index.aspx" by using `Index` class `TypeOf(Index)`

Comment: I can't go for that solution as I'm using WebForms MVP and all my pages inherits from  MvpPage<T>

Comment: I have found a solution. I have poste the code on my blog
http://massimilianopeluso.com/2011/03/31/strong-typed-response-redirect/